# Creating a labeled grid of colored squares

Tags: grid-layouts

I'd like to help some students with their project and I need to come up with a nice way of producing the following image:

[image]

The numbers will probably be loaded in a vector, such as:

```
v={4,7,8,10,14,3,15,9,0,1,2,5,12,6,11,13}
```

Now, the exact coloring and shading is not necessary, but I would like to see several ideas if possible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a variation on the following theme?

```
numbers = {4, 7, 8, 10, 14, 3, 15, 9, 0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 6, 11, 13};

Grid[
 Map[
  Framed[#,
    ContentPadding -> True, ImageSize -> {60, 60}, 
    Alignment -> Center,
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Darker@Red, Thick], 
    Background -> Directive[Lighter@Pink, Opacity[0.4]]
  ] &,
  ArrayReshape[
   Style[#, 32, Italic, FontFamily -> "Serif"] & /@ ToString /@ numbers,
   {4, 4}
  ],
  {2}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. There is a lot to learn here and this image is precisely what my students will need. This is extremely helpful.

Comment: @David Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
v = {4, 7, 8, 10, 14, 3, 15, 9, 0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 6, 11, 13};
With[{p = Reverse /@ (Transpose@Partition[v, 4]), 
  z = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}]},
 Show[
  ArrayPlot[z, Mesh -> True,
   ColorRules -> {0 -> LightRed}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thickness[0.02]], 
   Epilog -> 
    MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, 28], #2 - {1/2, 1/2}] &, p, {2}]],
  ArrayPlot[z, ColorRules -> {_ -> None}, Mesh -> True, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.01]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I'm going to look carefully at this.

Comment: To help with locating each piece of text, is there a way to add ticks to the outer frame that indicate the position of each text number. I tried z=ConstantArray[0,{4,4}], then ArrayPlot[z, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All], but the ticks give the two and column number.

Comment: @David  Apologies for delay. `Reverse/@Transpose[Partition[v,4]` puts matrix into a  format to allow placement of text consistent with the  coordinate system of the graphic. `ArrayPlot` is just a container and overlaying meshes just a device to get the framed appearance.. `MapIndexed` places the transformed matrix in the positions of the graphic with the offset to make them central.  The left hand lower corner is {0,0} and the other corners going counter-clockwise are {4,0}, {4,4},{0,4}. MapIndexed just subtracts {1/2,1/2}. For middle of square {m,n}->{m,n}-{1/2,1/2}. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does, thanks.